# ubuntu 16.04 printer is no longer available

Tags: package-management, printing, dpkg, dependencies, cups-lpd

Today i found that printing is no longer possible.
1. i can only print in pdf
2. Cups says CUPS SERVER ERROR there was an error during the cups operation, failed to connect to server
3. did the following

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 printer-driver-gutenprint : Depends: cups (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: cups-client (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

4. read various q+a and run commands like bpkd, autoremove, autoclean. Nothing

until the upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 system run smoothly.

please help

Comment: It seems like you may have an ancient version of cups.  My 14.04 system has version 1.7.2 Please input the command `apt-cache policy cups` in a terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: And if you run 'sudu apt-get install cups' ?

Comment: @SorenA Have the same problem. Sudo apt-get install cups' and its variants give: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
        Recommends: printer-driver-gutenprint but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: I solved this by selecting the "Experimental packages", which has the latest version of cups: `cups 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1`. See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/2.1.3-4ubuntu0.1